# Quotient Rule in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $g$ be a function that is continuous at 0 and satisfies $g(0) \ne 0$. Set $f(x) = x^2/g(x)$.

1) Explain why the quotient rule does not apply to $f$.
2) Show that $f$ is differentiable at 0 and calculate $f'(0)$

For 1) I don't understand why the quotient rule does not apply to $f$.

I have:

$f'(x) = \frac{2xg(x) - x^2g'(x)}{g(x)^2}$

And I'm unsure how this shows that the quotient rule does not apply to $f$, I think I am good for 2). Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $g$ is not necessarily differentiable at $x=0$.

To compute that derivative of $f$ at $x=0$, just go through by definition:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{h^{2}/g(h)-0}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{h}{g(h)}\\
&=\left(\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h\right)\left(\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{g(h)}\right)\\
&=0\cdot\dfrac{1}{g(0)}\\
&=0,
\end{align*}
where the continuity of $g$ at $x=0$ is used.

Comment: So since we do not know whether g is differentiable at x = 0, we cannot use the quotient rule for f, thank you.